# Updating input controls on checkbox value

Tags: angular, checkbox

Apologize for the lengthy explanation as I am not sure how to best portray my issue/question.
I am quite new to Angular2 and typescript (only been coding in it for a couple months now) and haven't been coding for many years so pretty much a rank newbie all over again....

I have a dynamic list of Expense Types in my page that I populate when changing my organization value.  The list is comprised of a checkbox and a text field that replaces the label of the checkbox.  I have the text field being enabled when checking the checkbox but how I am doing it is very poorly structured.  I will show my code below shortly.

My process that I am looking for is as follows:

1. The Expense Type list is populated from an array I obtain from my
   database based on OrganizationID
2. This works fine with my code and html below by two way binding to the input controls
3. The text boxes start out as disabled so only showing values.  When I click a checkbox, I want only the related text box for that checkbox to be enabled
4. Again, I have this working, although how I got it to work was not correct I am sure...
5. When the text box is enabled, I will be able to update the Expense Type and then save it through additional functionality
6. I have been told I now need to add a second text box to the list so that I will have two text boxes associated to each checkbox.
7. What I have been able to do so far is confirm I can't figure out how to get the second text box to be updated by the checkbox the way I have implemented the process so far.

My html code with the second text box just added to try to get it working and I will format later

**Update**
After more investigation, I have updated the question with the answer by adding [(ngModel)]=""expenseType.checked" to the checkbox input and updated the description text box to use [disabled]="!"expenseType.checked"

I also did more reading to then look at how to hide the category text box until checked and found using [hidden] isn't exactly perfect either so changed the category text box to use *ngIf="expenseType.checked"

I also removed the referencing of the event object in the onChecked() method.  Will leave that in the code for use later

```html
<div>
  <label>Default Expense Types:</label>
  <div *ngFor="let expenseType of expenseTypes">
    <div class="checkBox">
      <input for="expenseTypeText"
             type="checkbox"
             class="checkBox"
             [checked]="false"
             (change)="onChecked($event)"
             [(ngModel)]="expenseType.checked"
             >
      <input type="text"
             class="text_style"
             id="expenseTypeText"
             [disabled]="!expenseType.checked"
             [(ngModel)]="expenseType.description"
             >
      <input *ngIf="expenseType.checked"
             type="text"
             class="text_style"
             id="expenseTypeCategory"
             [(ngModel)]="expenseType.category"
             >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My onChecked method from my class

```js
onChecked($event) {
 /* *if ($event.target.checked == true) {
    $event.target.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;}
  else {
    $event.target.nextElementSibling.disabled = true;
  }* */ removed
}
```

A capture of the expenstype list I on the page as of now.
[List with two text boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSMsV.png)

These two sets of code work to populate the text boxes with expenseType description and category.  The issue I have is I am not able to enable the category box in the same manner as my description box.  I am very sure it is because of my implementation to access the text box in my onChecked() method.  All attempts so far have only enable or disable all category text boxes at the same time.  I can't get access to the specific category text the same as I am doing for the description text box.

I am sure a revision to use an index in the ngFor and possibly ViewChildren or even a form and form groups/controls might be the correct way to go but I can't get it figured out.

Ultimately, (in a great world, I would like to have the category text box hidden until I check the checkbox and when I do, the description field is enabled and the category field appears and is enabled ready to edit.  I will take what I can get though just to enable and disable both text boxes when selecting a checkbox....

I appreciate any all feedback and I am sure I will also get some feedback on parsing the event array to get at siblings.  I ask for any and all help please.

Comment: You can connect checkbox value to disable attribute directly through component variable.

E.g. <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isSomethingChecked">

<input type="text" [disabled]="isSomethingChecked">

Comment: Thanks you for the reply laser.  This, however, enables all text boxes in the list not just the textboxes that are "associated" with the checkbox that was selected

Comment: So, after more investigation using the answer from laser, I have found that using the ngModel works and instead of using a random value or something generic, which ends up impacting all text boxes in the list, I put the checked value from the checkbox input into the ngModel and the disabled attribute on the text boxes.     <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="expenseType.checked">     <input type="text" [disabled]="!expenseType.checked">   This worked out perfectly and I was able to get rid of the element referencing in the onchecked method.  Thanks laser for putting me in the right direction.

Comment: I have put my comment as an answer, you can improve that if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The *right* way to connect inputs for you will be the following pattern:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isSomethingChecked"> 
<input type="text" [disabled]="isSomethingChecked">
```